# Is it common to use "dash into something" as in this sentence? "I'll dash into this book"

Tags: slang

My intention is to say that I will get involved with this book and read it very fast.

Is it correct to use this expression or even common to say so?

EDIT: I'm adding other uses that I'm wondering if are they common or not:

"I'll dash into my homework"
"He dashed into his tasklist"
"She is dashing into her schedule"

Comment: _"I'll dash into this book"_ is not idiomatic English. You will never hear the verb _dash_ used in these ways by a native English speaker.

Comment: But you *could* **dash *through* the book**.  *You need to buckle down, young man, and spend more time studying. You dash through your homework far too often!*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo _Through,_ perhaps _over,_ but not _into._

Comment: @P. E. Dant: yes. The problem here is not the verb but the preposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. *Dash* usually implies running in the sense you're using, and specifically running a relatively short distance. Take, for example, the olympic events 100m dash, 200m dash, etc. (Though other meanings also exist for "dash"; e.g., a small amount of something in a recipe.)

So you might *dash* into a store, for example, if you were literally going to run in very quickly from across the parking lot. But even in that case, "dash" would be a bit uncommon. Probably just "run in" would be more typical.

But the phrase you're looking for is ***dive in***. [From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dive):

> to plunge into some matter or activity

Example sentence from MW:

> she *dove* into her studies

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's much more common to say "He jumped right into his homework," or "I'll jump right on that," not "He dashed into his homework." I'm not saying people wouldn't understand you, but just from my experience I have rarely heard "dashed into ..." before.

Comment: I did a search on Google books, trying to find one example where someone used _dash_ with a less-than-literal destination. I found dozens of instances of _dashed into her room, dashed into the house, dashed into his office,_ etc., but they were all physical places. I finally thought I managed to find one – _dashed into his music_ – but, upon closer scrutiny, I found out the original said, "dashed into his music **room**." I agree with you: it's understandable, but highly unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples I've seen where it is used to imply reckless actions related to intangibles:

"Dash into cash/stocks/bonds" appears as headlines talking about investments.

"The government's headlong dash into Brexit", "Australia's dash into war in 1914 was no knee-jerk response", "she thinks if I was really in love I'd dash into marriage like a mad thing" describe changes of state rather than physical places.

But as "dash into" is so much more commonly used with real things or locations, that "I dashed into my homework" would only be used literally - "I dashed into my homework, knocking the books to the floor".